# Run iOS UI Automation on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, ubuntu, instruments

I am able to use iOS Instruments by Xcode or run the test written in javascript by shell but I have a question about it. Is it possible to run these test on Ubuntu, not being possible to install Xcode on it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, if you're actually using Xcode for development? There might be a hack around it, but that wouln't be anything good.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so I realize that is not legal to do this...

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406839/1019630) the low-level tool chain for Xcode (the gcc compiler family, the gdb debugger, etc.) is all open source and common to Unix and Linux platforms. But the IDE--the editor, project management, indexing, navigation, build system, graphical debugger, visual data modeling, SCM system, refactoring, project snapshots, etc.--is a Mac OS X Cocoa application, and is not portable.

So, if you're using Xcode to develop iOS apps, you need to use Mac OS X as your operating system. The ideal option is to have a Mac computer, however if you don't care about the legal issues, you can install it on your non-Mac computer, or just as a virtual machine inside your Ubuntu, using Virtual Box or VMWare.

Unless you plan to use a third party IDE to develop iOS apps which won't necessarily let you have native apps.

Comment: Thank you Neeku, I only need to test iOS apps but I was looking for a tool to perform these tests not necessarily on OSx machines. For example, I'd need to run javascript test file (written with iOS UI Automation API) for an iPad on a Linux machine rather than an OSx one. Thank you for your reply.