# xcodebuild in docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, xcodebuild

I have multiple software solutions with several being iOS based apps.
I am taking the opportunity and looking at my CI scripts using Gitlab Runners / Docker implementation. 
I have moved the majority of my work over but im left looking at my iOS apps. Is there a way to run xcodebuild in a docker container?

Thanks

Comment: This looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574769/can-i-run-xcode-in-a-docker-container