# Run react native on docker?

Tags: ios, react-native, docker, docker-compose, react-native-ios

I am trying to run react-native on docker. I am new for docker, I have searched for react-native docker image but it only shows react-native-android image. How can I run react-native project on docker and run on iOS simulator.

Please write steps so that I can start react-native project on docker.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `iOS simulator` in `Docker`. The reason is that you can't run `Xcode` on any platform other than `MacOS`. And Docker only supports Windows and Linux platforms.

More you can find here:

[Can I run Xcode in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574769/can-i-run-xcode-in-a-docker-container)

[Can you Run Xcode in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406151/can-you-run-xcode-in-linux)