# How to deploy the app in Iphone simulator from Windows

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

I'm trying to deploy my app in i phone simulator. My Mac and windows is connected in visual studio.Also the build is successful. And the deployment is also successful but my app is not getting displayed in emulator because of Xcode version.

As you can see in this image below

[image: screenshot of error]

I'm using Xcode version 7.0.1 and I cant use the Xcode more than this version because it wont support my Mac version 10.11.6. So how to deploy the app on the current version of Xcode. Will I be able to specify in the visual studio properties that the app should deploy in xcode version 7.0.1? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that if you can't upgrade your Xcode version because of your Mac version, then you will need to install a Virtual Box and see if you can get a later OS version installed on that. I've had this issue in the past as well when creating Android apps on a Windows machine. I installed a Virtual Box application with Linux and used that to code my Android application.

EDIT: Here is a link to a stackoverflow post regarding running Xcode on Linux: [Can you Run Xcode in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406151/can-you-run-xcode-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. According to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#mac. We know that:

- The minimum required Mac operation system version is macOS Sierra
  (10.12)
- For xamarin.iOS: The iOS that ships with Xcode 9

Also if we want to deploy xamarin.iOS project, we should install VS for Mac on Mac pc too. And the requirements of [Visual Studio 2017 for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-mac) should be:

- macOS Sierra 10.12: Community, Professional, and Enterprise.
- the latest version of Xcode 8.3 requires macOS Sierra 10.12, therefore Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac projects also require that minimum version.

So if you do want to deploy a xamarin.iOS app, try to upgrade your Mac pc's system version to 10.12.