# i want to make the standalone mobile application for ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

1. i have made a project in expo for android as well as ios but when i
   try to make the standalone application for ios it shows me a error
   "Your project must have a bundleIdentifier set in app.json. See
   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#2-configure-appjson"
   but in the app.json file in ios section i give it a field named
   bundleIdentifier and i givethe same value to the android package and
   the value is ""com.react.myappname"". but is just shows me the same
   error again and again. i am making this build using windows 10,help
   me on that.

   {   "expo": {
       "name": "com.projectname.app",

   ```
   "description": "This project is really great.",
   "slug": "projectname",
   "privacy": "public",
   "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
   "platforms": ["ios"],
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "orientation": "portrait",
   "icon": "./assets/iconios.png",
   "splash": {
     "image": "./assets/splashios.png",
     "resizeMode": "contain",
     "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
   },
   "updates": {
     "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
   },
   "assetBundlePatterns": [
     "**/*"
   ],
   "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier":"com.react.projectname"
   },

      },
   ```

   "expo": {
       "name": "com.projectname.app",

   ```
   "description": "This project is really great.",
   "slug": "projectname",
   "privacy": "public",
   "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
   "platforms": [ "android"],
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "orientation": "portrait",
   "icon": "./assets/playstore-icon.png",
   "splash": {
     "image": "./assets/splash.png",
     "resizeMode": "contain",
     "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
   },
   "updates": {
     "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
   },
   "assetBundlePatterns": [
     "**/*"
   ],
   "android": {
     "package":"com.react.projectname",
     "config": {
       "googleMaps": {
         "apiKey": "AIzaSyD4KuDsSesrWf_iDn3WDTnwxqekZoC9qk0"
       }
     }
   }   } }
   ```

   ## Heading

Answer (score 0):

For ios you need to set your bundleIdentifier also in Xcode.. and in Windows10 Xcode not available. you need mac for building & running ios app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't do that in `windows` environment. Either you need to a `virtual` machine set up in your windows machine or explicitly a `ios` machine borrowed from a friend. And then you need `Xcode` installed in it. All the development projects' builds create a file that can be open inside Xcode. Then only you can run it on an ios `emulator` or debug using a real iphone device.

Comment: ok so can i use the linux server to run this command will it run on windows?

Comment: @RahulKumar, No any other OS including `linux`, you definitely need a `macOS` environment. You may be able to build, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406151/can-you-run-xcode-in-linux